# Como redirecionar de uma subpasta para a pasta raiz com htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, apache

Olá, gostaria de fazer um redirecionamento com HTACCESS mas não estou sabendo como fazer.
A estrutura do site está em: `site.com.br/subpasta` gostaria de fazer a mudança do meu site para apenas `site.com.br`, mas como ele já está rodando não gostaria de perder os acessos futuros aos links antigos.

Por exemplo, quando alguém clicar em um link antigo: `site.com.br/subpasta/1234` gostaria que  fosse direcionado para `site.com.br/1234` como posso fazer isso?